# Ubuntu 22.04 Error from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: connection refused

Tags: docker, ubuntu-22.04, docker-registry

In Ubuntu 22.04

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# sudo systemctl daemon-reload
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# sudo systemctl enable docker
Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# 
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# sudo systemctl restart docker
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# 
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# sudo docker pull cassandra:latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:48086->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-11-08 20:22:55 CET; 11min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 272072 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 15
     Memory: 37.7M
        CPU: 638ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─272072 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Nov 08 20:22:55 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:22:55.320001583+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Nov 08 20:22:55 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:22:55.353839818+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Nov 08 20:22:55 k8s-eu-1-master systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 08 20:23:07 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:23:07.456049976+01:00" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:48086->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused"
Nov 08 20:23:07 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:23:07.456096778+01:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:48086->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused"
Nov 08 20:23:07 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:23:07.458039838+01:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/images/create returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:48086->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused"
Nov 08 20:32:06 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:32:06.231824815+01:00" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:43104->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused"
Nov 08 20:32:06 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:32:06.231929019+01:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:43104->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused"
Nov 08 20:32:06 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:32:06.233897769+01:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.43/images/create returned error: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:43104->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused"
Nov 08 20:32:10 k8s-eu-1-master dockerd[272072]: time="2023-11-08T20:32:10.259620826+01:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=544ab9c3758d8293d505aead2429bd2a6fff065672bc83c171d4834393814dc6 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
```

But the `hello-world` docker example works fine :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

This is the output of `docker info` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# docker info
    Client: Docker Engine - Community
     Version:    24.0.7
     Context:    default
     Debug Mode: false
     Plugins:
      buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
        Version:  v0.11.2
        Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
      compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
        Version:  v2.21.0
        Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
    
    Server:
     Containers: 4
      Running: 0
      Paused: 0
      Stopped: 4
     Images: 1
     Server Version: 24.0.7
     Storage Driver: overlay2
      Backing Filesystem: extfs
      Supports d_type: true
      Using metacopy: false
      Native Overlay Diff: true
      userxattr: false
     Logging Driver: json-file
     Cgroup Driver: systemd
     Cgroup Version: 2
     Plugins:
      Volume: local
      Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
      Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
     Swarm: inactive
     Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
     Default Runtime: runc
     Init Binary: docker-init
     containerd version: 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
     runc version: v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
     init version: de40ad0
     Security Options:
      apparmor
      seccomp
       Profile: builtin
      cgroupns
     Kernel Version: 5.15.0-88-generic
     Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
     OSType: linux
     Architecture: x86_64
     CPUs: 10
     Total Memory: 58.86GiB
     Name: k8s-eu-1-master
     ID: ca48bc0b-922b-47b6-bae4-85d5d911436c
     Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
     Debug Mode: false
     Experimental: false
     Insecure Registries:
      127.0.0.0/8
     Live Restore Enabled: false
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when doing a docker build, it was resolved with the command below that @Raphael10 posted.

add valid DNS server to `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
 nameserver 8.8.8.8
 nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding these two lines in /etc/resolv.conf

```
    nameserver 8.8.8.8
    nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

And then:

```
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# sudo systemctl restart docker
```